# Display specific product view in block

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise

I'm trying to display specific product in `products-view` by `product-id` in block.

I searched but I only found how to display product list in as:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" 
name="home.catalog.product.list" 
alias="products_homepage" 
category_id="365" 
template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Looking for help.

Comment: No need to add your name and are using magento-enterprise edition ?

Comment: Sorry my mistake

Comment: No prob. are you using magento-enterprise edition or community ?

Comment: using Magento Enterprise